# Visual Studio 2017 publish ftp doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, ftp, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to publish my project to FTP with Visual Studio 2017 RC. The problem is with uploading files, it doesn't work. I tried to folder and works fine, but to external FTP not.

Why i want to do this? Because it's .net core project and i want to deploy on linux production environment.

What i'm doing wrong?

//edit:
I'm using vsftpd on ubuntu 16.04 and connecting with passive mode.

ftp://hostname with user and password data. path is "app_dev" it's folder on ftp.

Comment: I checked something. It creating folder on ftp but don't copy files.

Comment: I have the same issue. File system publish works fine, ftp publishing for the same ASP.NET Core project (before migrating to .csproj) in VS2015 worked fine. FTP publish in 2017 nothing. It says it's connected, then bundles everything then it's "published successfully" without copying any file. I tried several ftps

Comment: Just adding myself to the list.  I just spent 2 hours trying to get ftp publish to work.  I think its broken.. I didn't use it in vs 2015 so cant comment.  Filezilla works.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24972/publish-not-working-in-vs-2017-ide.html
Comments seem to suggest it is broken now. Filezilla it is for now.

Comment: same problem I hope it gets fixed soon

Comment: If you're going to manually FTP across to your server, be aware that this can happen => https://www.hanselman.com/blog/13HoursDebuggingASegmentationFaultInNETCoreOnRaspberryPiAndTheSolutionWas.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Only way that I found is to create a local drive letter that appoints to the ftp. 
Sorry no better answer...

Answer (score 0):

i had similar issue in the past. What i did was use other ftp client to publish the app after publishing to local folder.

But still you should try getting their deployment script